# How to fill drop down dynamically using ClientContext object in sharepoint 2010

Tags: client-object-model

I need to fill the dropdown from the sharepoint list using ClientContext object.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question further.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these links having good examples:

http://khakicampbelldeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-populate-drop-down-lists-and-save-list-items/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5e96d47f-e3b9-4502-bb66-6feb728bcabf/populate-list-fields-in-dropdown?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

small example from the code:

```
function PopulateDepartmentsSuccess() {

//Clear out current entries

var ddlDepartment = this.document.getElementById(‘ddlDepartment’);

ddlDepartment.options.length = 0;

//Iterate through new entries and populate DDL

var listEnumerator = _allDepartmentItems.getEnumerator();

 while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {

var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();

ddlDepartment.options[ddlDepartment.options.length] = new Option(currentItem.get_item(“Title”), currentItem.get_item(“ID”));

}

}
```